# MySQL Trigger doesnt execute if a column's default NULL value changes to some value

Tags: mysql

Here is the MYSQL Trigger that I have written:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER updtrigger BEFORE UPDATE ON myTable
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    IF (OLD.column IS NOT NULL AND NEW.column IS NOT NULL AND NEW.column != OLD.column) THEN 
        SET NEW.col_updated_on = NOW();
    END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

If `column` has a value (say, "movie"), and I update it to get new value, "movie,music", the trigger gets executed and `col_updated_on` should have the current timestamp.

However, when `column` is NULL and I update it to get the new value, "movie", the `col_updated_on` column will still show me the old timestamp.

Please let me know what change I must do to check for this condition as well.

Thanks in advance for your replies.

I have another question. Is the below pseudo possible??

Here are my two tables - 
    `myTable`(id, someId, col_updated_on);
        `myOtherTable`(id, col1, col2);

`myTable`.someId has a 1-on-1 relation with `myOtherTable`.id

I want to update `myTable`.col_updated_on whenever `myOtherTable`.col1 and `myOtherTable`.col2 are updated. How do i do this? and should i use "BEFORE UPDATE" or "AFTER UPDATE"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`NULL`-safe equality operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to):

```
IF NOT OLD.column <=> NEW.column THEN
```

However, note that MySQL's [`TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) data type can (and, by default, will) [automatically update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/timestamp-initialization.html) whenever a record is updated, making such a trigger unnecessary.

But also, you *REALLY* shouldn't store multiple items in a delimited string in a relational database like MySQL. Read up on [database design](http://r937.com/relational.html), especially one-to-many relationships: one would fare much better by having a separate table, in which each record links an identifier (key) from your existing (foreign) table to a single item; one would then [join](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) the tables together as required in your queries.

Comment: i wanted to use a trigger because i need to update the TIMESTAMP column only on updating few columns..